# Error de servidor en la aplicación '/' - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Amigos tengo este problema creo que se debe a la sesión. :(

[image: Error1]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero te recomiendo pongas un punto de interrupción en la línea que muestras y valides si `user.Identity` no es nulo. Si no lo fuera modifica la linea asi

```
var jUser = ((ClaimsIdentity)user.Identity).FindFirst(ClaimTypes.UserData)?.Value;
```

El `?` hace que si el resultado anterior es nulo devuelve nulo y si no accede a la propiedad `Value`

Comment: voy  a probar.. :)